# Android application with maps and custom places

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to make and Android app which has a map and a list of nearest *custom* places. By *custom* I mean places which may be not present in Google Places. What is the best way to do this?

At first I thought that Google Maps and Google Places List can be a good idea but I didn't like API keys (but if there is no other way I will deal with them) and I didn't quite understood the [Adding Place part](https://developers.google.com/places/android/add-place). How many Places can I add?

Are there any other services I can read about?

I believe that I don't have to implement nearest place search myself as it is a common task, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If.. "by *custom* you mean places which may be not present in Google Places", then there should be no point in using the Google Places List (I assume you are talking about the Auto complete.) even if you like the API keys....

I think you should do handle and show your custom places outside of the Google Maps API logic. Like, create your custom list view somewhere outside of the Maps view, or overlay on top of it.